# How to Assign an Integer Value to Unsigned Char* in C

Tags: c, types

I have an unsigned char* type and want to assign it an integer value. How can I do it in C?

Comment: Could you provide some context?

Comment: you want to assign to it the address of an integer or its value?

Comment: If u try to go ahead of 255, the value will reset to 0.the limit is 255.

Comment: Do you want to assign it to an integer value or do you want to assign to it an integer value?

Comment: `unsigned char *c = 3;` But I don't think this is really what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it, with an appropriate cast:

```
unsigned char *pointer = (unsigned char *) 0xdeadf00d;
```

This does exactly what you asked for, it assigns an integer value to a pointer to `unsigned char`. This is not a very *useful* thing to be doing, but that's how you do it.

Of course there's no requirement (that I'm aware of) that this is even possible; your architecture's idea of a pointer might not support this, in which case I guess the compiler will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
unsigned char *ucrp,*ucr2p;
unsigned char ucr2='X';
int Integr_val=320;
ucr2p=&ucr2 ;
ucrp=(unsigned char *)&Integr_val;
*ucr2p= Integr_val;
return printf("\n %c,%i\n %c,%i",*ucrp,*ucrp,*ucr2p,*ucr2p);
}
```

With this example you can basically understand what loss you are performing.A char without explicit typecasting can convert an integer value.

Output:-

```
@,64

@,64
```

Comment: That's assigning the address of an `int` to the `unsigned char *`, which isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:- Is it okay..if not plz modify

Answer (score -2):

```
unsigned char* a;
int b = 1;

( *a ) = ( unsigned char ) b;
```